# How to create and share the contact in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, vcf-vcard

How to create the contact in locally with Name and phone number and share the created contact to other apps like whatsapp, social media's etc...

By using `vcard_maintained` library https://pub.dev/packages/vcard_maintained, we are able to create the contact, But not able to share through the apps.

I tried this,

```
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:vcard_maintained/vcard_maintained.dart';

var vCard = VCard();
vCard.firstName = 'FirstName';
vCard.middleName = 'MiddleName';
vCard.workPhone = '312-555-1212';
final path = await _localPath;
vCard.saveToFile('$path/contact.vcf');
Share.shareFiles(['$path/contact.vcf'], text: 'Great picture');


Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}
```

But getting `format of this vcard is not support` error.

Comment: Can you please add an example of the vCard that is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working example.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:vcard_maintained/vcard_maintained.dart';

void shareAllVCFCard(BuildContext context, {required List<VCard> vCard}) async {
  try {
    List<String> vcsCardPath = <String>[];
    int index = 0;
    for (final card in vCard) {
      index++;
      var vCardAsString = card.getFormattedString();
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final path = directory.path;
      var pathAsText = "$path/$index.txt";

      var contactAsFile = File(await getFilePath(index.toString()));
      contactAsFile.writeAsString(vCardAsString);

      var vcf = contactAsFile
          .renameSync(contactAsFile.path.replaceAll(".txt", ".vcf"));
      vcsCardPath.add(vcf.path);
    }

    Share.shareFiles(vcsCardPath, text: 'Great picture');
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error Creating VCF File $e");
    return null;
  }
}


Future<String> getFilePath(String fileName) async {
  Directory appDocumentsDirectory =
      await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // 1
  String appDocumentsPath = appDocumentsDirectory.path; // 2
  String filePath = '$appDocumentsPath/$fileName.txt'; // 3

  return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately vcard_maintained is not maintained now :) If we try with plain vcard string, resolution doesn't work.

Comment: Works for all apps I've tested except WhatsApp. Did you ever get it to work for WhatsApp??